# Switching FreeBSD (OSS) audio to mono

Tags: freebsd, audio

Is there a way in FreeBSD (OSS) *without* restarting to toggle the audio output mono-only/stereo?

Setting `sysctl dev.pcm.0.play.vchanformat=s16le:1.0` doesn’t work – or perhaps I misunderstood something [here](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pcm&sektion=4&manpath=freebsd-release-ports).